# How can I prevent 2 Text in Box overlap each other using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement a 2 text using jetpack compose with these rules: if the text is short, time will be beside and if is long it goes to another line.
[image]

[image]

The problem is in some sizes, the text overlaps the time:

[image]

Here's the code snippet:

```
@Composable
fun TextMessageItem(body: String, userName: String, time: String) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = body,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart),
            overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
        )
        Text(
            text = time,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)

        )
    }
}
```

How can I solve the issue and have those rules?

Comment: The `Box` layout will always stack its children on top of each other. Try using  `Row` in your case

Comment: This requires you to get total line count and line width inside a `Layout` to set it properly. You can check this to see how implementation is done. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Flexible-Chat-Box

Comment: So useful, thank you! Please post it as the answer.